# Reloading Properties files when changed

Tags: java, spring, file, properties

I am loading Properties files to One class and then using the class throughout the application to get them.

```
public class PropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void loadProperties(final Properties props) throws IOException {
        super.loadProperties(props);
        for (final Object key : props.keySet()) {
            properties.put((String) key, props.getProperty((String) key));
        }
    }

    public String getProperty(final String name) {
        return properties.get(name);
    }

}
```

and in ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="propertiesUtil"
        class="com.test.PropertiesUtil">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:test/test.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I want to make sure that Properties file is reloaded whenever it's changed.

I have one listener class which initializes along with tomcat server.
and I have written below logic for file watcher

```
TimerTask task = new FileWatcher(new File("c:\\temp-reb\\config\\config.properties")) {
    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.belgacom.rosy.rebecca.utils.FileWatcher#onChange(java.io.File)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onChange(File file) {
        loadServiceProperties(file);
        loadMetadata();
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, new Date(), Long.valueOf(properties.getProperty("properties.file.timer.schedule"))); // repeat the check every second
```

problem is

> > 1. FileWatcher needs path to run, which I don't want to hardcode
> > 2. How do I tell spring to call properties to reload explicitly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. FileWatcher needs path to run, which I don't want to hardcode

Just give the relative path like a resource directory in same project folder, which you can get using the `getResource()` method. You can also use the [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to access like `user.dir` which is the use working directory.

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/test.properties");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

> 2. How do I tell spring to call properties to reload explicitly!

The way you are doing it currently seems ok to me. There might be other ways as well, but I don't see any flaw in the above process.

Comment: FileWatcher accepts File as argument. I can pass string to File. But getResource() doesn't return any one of them right.

Comment: Should use File.separator instead of "/"

Answer (score 1):

This is a winding road leading to really dark places. Spring per definition instantiates and maintains references to singletons. So if a client becomes injected with a dependency, keeps it, and the application context starts delivering new beans, you get in a real ugly state. If you do not use your properties as bean properties you should be OK, but mixing this is not really the way to go.

If anything I would try to limit the number of beans affected by reloading the properties and put them in special scopes. This way everytime your scope changes, you get a new bean with the newest configuration. At least you will have a defined lifecycle of properties and know exactly what you are up against.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you much. 
My Listener class/thread will be initiated once during server startup and never ends (yes it runs on infinite loop for it's own job)
and I need to do file watcher/reloading properties in this thread. It's not like normal web application. But I want to achieve the above requirement that whenever properties changed, load them. Can you please guide?

Comment: If you are Batchig, have a look at Spring Batch. If you are running on a command line application, kill the application context and reload it with all dependent beans before each cycle, if you can afford the performance overhead.

Comment: It's web application. something should never stop

Comment: What kind of properties are you trying to replace? How do they affect the system?

Comment: Properties which can change the application process from one direction to another.

Comment: Changing arbitrary aspects of a running application by reloading properties on the fly without any life cycle management? I was never brave enough to try this :-)

Comment: may bot completely. yes but paritally. :)