# Changing the properties file while the application is running

Tags: java, file

I have a attribute in properties file. say 'x'. 
In my Java class, I use this x in a loop. So the first time loop is executed, it loads from properties file and from the second time, it takes value from memory without loading the props file every time. Now if I want to change the value of x in the properties file, can i load that value without restarting the application? If yes, how?

Also is there any Java equivalent for Session_OnStart in .net? I heard Session_OnStart in .net serves this purpose

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815008/reloading-properties-files-when-changed?rq=1

Comment: You can have a front end screen that allows you to change this value.  Then upon change also update the session...

Comment: Please describe the functionality you're trying to implement. This sounds like a workaround with a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load and parse the properties each time a variable is requested.

```
class RefreshingProperties extends Properties {

  private final File file;

  public RefreshingProperties (File file) throws IOException { 
    this.file = file;
    refresh ();
  }

  private void refresh () throws IOException {
    load (new FileInputStream (file));
  }

  @Override
  public String getProperty (String name) {
    try { refresh (); }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    return super.get (name);
  }
}
```

You can tweak this to reload only whenever a certain time period expires

Comment: If I have to use this in my class, do I need to load RefreshingProperties instead of Properties file? I mean, instead of Properties prop = new Properties(), RefreshingProperties prop = new RefreshingProperties() ??

Comment: Also, will there be any performance issues as i keep on reloading the prop file?

Comment: Yes, obviously you need to use the class to make use of its functionality. Yes, obviously there are resource and performance costs associated with reading and parsing a file as opposed to not doing it.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks! And another question. What is HttpSessionListener used for? Is it similar to Session_Onstart in .net?

Comment: Session listeners receive callbacks on web session creation and destruction. I don't know anything about .NET